# Visual Studio Forgets To Quote Html Attributes

Tags: visual-studio

From time to time, my Visual Studio "forgets" to quote html attributes (based on the Text Editor->Html-Format option). This has been around since at least version 2003 and is still a problem in 2008. Are there any bullet-proof ways to handle this issue?

Comment: Out of curiosity, does this also happen if you use XHTML? For me, it *mostly* works correctly.

Comment: Whenever I notice it it's inside .ASPX or .ASCX not sure if plain xml, html, xhtml work ok - will check it next time Visual Studio forgets... :-(

Answer (score 0):

Are you manually typing them, or are you talking about the automagically rendered HTML of built in ASP.net controls?

When I manually type mine it quotes unless I start the attribute without a quote and use tab to completion.  Otherwise it works fine.